# Create logs for Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, logging, identityserver4

I'm trying to figure out how to get more detailed logs out of Identity Server 4, especially if things go wrong. I have read their documentation here http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/logging.html However, I can't seem to get it to work. For one I don't use serilog and I have the IS4 running on a server I don't have remote access to so console logging is not going to work for me.

As such, I've tried to inject my own custom logging library that I have with the following:

```
public class Temp : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() { }
}

public class CustomLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly IDatabaseLoggerService _databaseLoggerService;

    public CustomLogger(IDatabaseLoggerService databaseLoggerService)
    {
        _databaseLoggerService = databaseLoggerService;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if(exception == null) return;

        _databaseLoggerService.Fatal(new LogErrorDetails
        {
            Exception = exception,
            Message = "LIS - " + formatter
        });
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return new Temp();
    }
}

public class CustomLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly IDatabaseLoggerService _databaseLoggerService;

    public CustomLoggerProvider(IDatabaseLoggerService databaseLoggerService)
    {
        _databaseLoggerService = databaseLoggerService;
    }

    public void Dispose() { }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return new CustomLogger(_databaseLoggerService);
    }
}
```

As you can see its fairly straightforward because at this point I don't need it polished, just need it working, and I'll work on the proper implementation of it later once I have the sample working.

Now to set this up I did it in the Startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //code emmited
    var serviceProvider = app.ApplicationServices;
    var dbLogger = serviceProvider.GetService<IDatabaseLoggerService>();
    loggerFactory.AddProvider(new CustomLoggerProvider(dbLogger));
}
```

However, I don't see any logs about it, the only thing I saw was the occasional anti-forgery token error that now pops up and that is it:

> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext httpContext)

What I would like to see is if a token request was successful or if it failed and why, but I'm not seeing any of it.

How would I go to accomplish higher level of logging for Identity Server 4?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add your logger right into the `WebHostBuilder` giving you probably most insightful logs.

You can start of by creating an extension method to keep things nice and clean. We just need to add a singleton of our logger factory to the DI.

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder UseCustomLogger(this IWebHostBuilder builder, CustomLogger logger = null, bool dispose = false)
    {
        if (builder == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
        builder.ConfigureServices(collection =>
            collection.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory>(services => new CustomLoggerFactory(logger, dispose)));
        return builder;
    }
```

Factory itself would be very simple.

```
public class CustomLoggerFactory : ILoggerFactory
{
    private readonly CustomLoggerProvider _provider;

    public CustomLoggerFactory(ILogger logger = null, bool dispose = false)
    {
        _provider = new CustomLoggerProvider(logger, dispose);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _provider.Dispose();
    }

    public Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return _provider.CreateLogger(categoryName);
    }
}
```

You can then add your logger in `Program.cs`:

```
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseCustomLogger();
```

Lastly, looking at your logger implementation - you will need to create instance of `IDatabaseLoggerService` in the factory so that the logger can be created. Similar approach can of course be used with the ASP.NET Core DI.

Comment: Do you have a more concrete example? I've tried to follow what you have above but I am rather confused. Where does the CustomLoggerProvider come from and what is in there? Where would I link my own implementation of the logger that I already have?

Comment: @Bojan it comes from your code. The only thing you were missing is the factory that uses the provider to create the logger.

Comment: @Bojan also the reason you’re not seeing some logs is because your logger logic checks for exception, but if the token auth was not successful - no exception is thrown so it won’t be logged with your logger.

Comment: So how do I capture token auth, successful and not?

Comment: @Bojan Implement more logging states than just fatal exception and then those kind of logs will start flowing through.

Comment: Fatal is only internal my own logging service, the ILogger implementations that I have accepts any logging states and just says use fatal which is internal to my own logger.

Comment: @Bojan that's correct, but you have `if(exception == null) return;` statement which will be true for pretty much all `Information`, `Trace`, `Debug`, etc. log states which are the kind of log states that are used to capture information whether token auth was successful or not. So basically you shortcircuit in most of the logger calls.

Comment: Sorry, I should of clarified that I have removed that line. Even after I still was only getting same as before, which is no logs.